# Insert data to Visual studio local DB, using C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, insert

I am making an application, and I added a local database in visual studio. It all works fine while logging into app using crediantials stored in the database. But while adding new records, the query runs with no error but data is not actually stored in data base. Every thing else is working fine, except for the data not being stored.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@" Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security = True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into users(username,password,phone,adress,father_name,email)VALUES('"+username.Text+ "','"+password.Text+ "','"+phone.Text+ "','"+adress.Text+ "','"+fathername.Text+ "','"+email.Text+"')",con);
try
{
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   MessageBox.Show(username.Text + " Has been Added");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
 finally
 {
   con.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Does the `Database1.mdf` file have the `Copy to Output Directory` Property set to `Copy Always`? -- BTW, you should learn how to use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) to set the values, string concatenation is not (really) the way to go -- SqlCommand is also disposable. In this context, declare disposable objects with `using` statements, it will generate a `try / finally` block for you under the hood

Comment: yes.login system is working well

Comment: As per @Jimi see [Visual Studio: Copying files to Debug or Release folder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx)

Comment: Its already set to copy always, query runs with no error, even if i try to upload image , it also goes to output directory. just new data is not being inserted

Comment: You want `Copy if newer` not `Copy always` as `Copy always` overwrites any changes from the last run.